# Is there a possibility to import a diagram from google sheets into a new file with a macro?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

I want to import a graphical evaluation (diagram) into a new file using a macro. So the evaluation should not be inserted on a new sheet in the associated file, but a completely new file should be created, in which the graphical evaluation (in the form of a combination diagram) is then copied. The file should be either a Google Sheets or an Excel file. The combination diagram already exists and is located in a Google sheet, but it should be copied into a new file automatically with the help of a macro and the corresponding button.

I have already tried to start a macro and opened a new file and copied the diagram, but it only showed this code which is pretty useless:

```
function AuswertungTest() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B25').activate();
};
```

It would be very kind of you to help me with that problem! :)

Comment: i would like to use importrange in the new file, but the step, that a new file gets created by using a macro is still unclear. @peh u have any idea?

Comment: When you say a 'combination diagram' you mean a chart?

Comment: yes basically a diagram yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to insert the diagram/chart in the newly created Spreadsheet, I have two solutions using Sheet [1] and EmbeddedChart [2] methods:

1) If you want to convert the chart to an image before inserting it:

```
function AuswertungTest() {
  //Sheet with diagram
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //Create new Spreadsheet in Drive and get its first Sheet
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("new spreadsheet");
  var newSheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  //Get the first chart and convert it to an image blob
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.getAs('image/jpeg');

  //Insert image in new spreadsheet
  newSheet.insertImage(chart, 2, 2)
};
```

2) If you want to insert the chart as it is (The chart will depend on the data in the new Spreadsheet):

```
function AuswertungTest() {
  //Sheet with diagram
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //Create new Spreadsheet in Drive and get its first Sheet
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("new spreadsheet");
  var newSheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  //Get the first chart and modify it to set the wanted position
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify().addRange(newSheet.getRange("A1:B8")).setPosition(2, 2, 0, 0).build();

  //Insert chart in new spreadsheet
  newSheet.insertChart(chart); 
};
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart

Comment: ok i will try tomorrow! I will tell you if it works then! Thank you !

Comment: Ok, so the first option works perfectly, but Nr2 does insert an empty chart to the new file, how does it insert the full chart with data?

Comment: Now I get the following error: Exception: You are not allowed to use SpreadsheetApp.create. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (Zeile 4, Datei "Makros"). How do I get the required permissions?

Comment: As is wrote in the answer for the 2nd option "The chart will depend on the data in the new Spreadsheet", so you'd need to have the data in the new spreadsheet using [importrange](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340), you can modify the data range with [addRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#addRange(Range)) function.

Comment: If it helped you please consider accepting the answer as correct.

Comment: how would the function look like with the addrange function? Can you show me?